# Setting the Durable Reduced Availability (DRA) attribute for a bucket using Storage Console

Tags: google-cloud-storage, bucket

When manually creating a new cloud storage bucket using the web-based storage console (https://console.developers.google.com/), is there a way to specify the DRA attribute? From the documentation, it appears that the only way to create buckets with that attribute is to either use Curl, gsutil or some other script, but not the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this.

At present, the storage console provides only a subset of the Cloud Storage API, so you'll need to use one of the tools you mentioned to create a DRA bucket.

For completeness, it's pretty easy to do this using gsutil (documentation at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mb):

```
gsutil mb -c DRA gs://some-bucket
```

Comment: Thanks Travis. This is as I suspected. AWS allows a per-object storage attribute (storage-class: REDUCED_REDUNDANCY) while GOOG allows the DRA at bucket-creation time only and that attribute cannot be changed later. Correct?

Comment: You're correct that for Google Cloud Storage, DRA is a bucket-level attribute (set at bucket creation time and not changable).  You can use gsutil mv to migrate objects between standard and DRA buckets.